# Combine Swinject and Realm

Tags: realm, swinject

thanks for that Framework. I really like the idea and I'm eager to use it! However, I'm currently trying to get this up and running with an app that uses realm as well. I initially tought, It might be a good idea to create a realmService which I inject to my models and which handles all of the realm write stuff.

Sadly, I can not make my mind up on how to do this properly. The Wether App example is great, but it doesn't cover any realm models. Any hint to point me into the correct direction or something? I tried via constructor and property but I just can't get it to work. I guess, I'm missing something conceptual.

Thanks, I'm eager to learn from you :)

Cheers

Comment: "Repository Pattern" is a good direction to cover your case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [forked the Weather example app](https://github.com/mrackwitz/SwinjectSimpleExample/commit/7a681fda239ff3d6d962e23a2d0050d39249b2ea) and added Realm in there, using Swinjects DI mechanism. Registering the service component pairs could look like this:

```
container.register(WeatherFetcher.self) { r in
    WeatherFetcher(networking: r.resolve(Networking.self)!)
    WeatherFetcher(networking: r.resolve(Networking.self)!,
                   realm: r.resolve(Realm.self)!)
}
container.register(Realm.Configuration.self) { _ in
    // not really necessary if you stick to the defaults everywhere
    return Realm.Configuration()
}
container.register(Realm.self) { r in
    try! Realm(configuration: r.resolve(Realm.Configuration.self)!)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @marius! I'll definitely check that out :)